# Flash: Runtime Shared Libraries - Memory Benefit?

Tags: flash, rsl

Suppose that I have two applications running on the same page.  I have the Libraries compiled into the SWF file:

Suppose

```
MemoryFootPrint(App A) = App A SWF + Libraries
MemoryFootPrint(App B) = App B SWF + Libraries
```

So:

```
MemoryFootPrint(total) = MemoryFootPrint(App A) + MemoryFootPrint(App B)
```

I am wondering if using RSL will lower the memory footprint of my two applicaitons.  Will they share the same libraries.  Will the memory footprint be:

```
MemoryFootPrint(total) = App A SWF + App B SWF + Libraries
```

OR

```
MemoryFootPrint(total) = App A SWF + App B SWF + Libraries + Libraries
```

---

Is RSL intended to just improve the download time (via caching) or does it also lower the memory foot print of an applicaiton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [adobe page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_02.html) does not speak about RSIs and the memory footprint other than saying:

> When you want to use a
>   dynamically-linked library, you
>   instruct the compiler to exclude that
>   library's contents from the
>   application SWF file when you compile
>   the application. You must provide
>   link-checking at compile time even
>   though the classes are not going to be
>   included in the final SWF file. **At run
>   time, the application loads the entire
>   library into the application SWF file,
>   which can result in slower startup
>   times and greater memory usage.**

From this I am assuming that there is no memory benefit from using RSIs.